# Python socket как отследить кто подключается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет

как узнать кто подключился? Можно-ли узнать ip того кто подключился?

Comment: Да, метод accept у сокета возвращает в том числе ip-адрес

Comment: @andreymal а можете пожалуйста быстро накидать пример? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Найдите абсолютно любой пример по сокетам в интернете, там всё будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример кода, все данные в `sock.accept()`

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 8001))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    try:
        client, addr = sock.accept()
        print(client, "\n", addr[0]) # выведет инфо о клиенте
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("ERR")
        sock.close()
        break
    else:
        result = client.recv(1024)
        client.send(b"Done!")
        client.close()
        print("Message: ", result.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: а можно-ли сделать чтобы выводилось только ip а то у меня выводит: ('999.9.9.9', 54734) то есть я имею ввиду что-бы выводилось только 999.9.9.9 как это сделать?

Comment: очень поможешь :)

Comment: @main Выведете как `addr[0]`